# Allow access to MySQL server installed on Amazon EC2 through C#

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed a mysql server 5.5 on amazon EC2 machine.
But cannot connect to it using C# using mysql-connecter-for-.net
I used:

```
Hostname = IP Address of EC2 machine.
Port = 3306
username =
password =
```

But, it fires up error: "The connection must be open and valid".

I can't find any tutorial over internet. Please guide.

Comment: You need to look at your security group.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks. I think your answer has a point. One more question. Does it matter, if i install mysql server using default linux command, "sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5" ? or i have to use "sudo yum install mysql-server".. m sorry m weak with linux fundamentals.

Comment: mine aren't much better.  Best ask a new question, this time on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your EC2 instance's security group. Add a MySQL entry with specify IP address (0.0.0.0/32 will accept connection from any IP address).